# Mac PAW app - get form authentication token

Tags: paw-app

I'm trying to authenticate automatically using Paw and to do this I need to

1. make a request to the login page
2. parse the html response to get an auth token from a login form
3. send the authentication request

but I don't know how to do that...

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In paw first set up the request to the login page. Then in a second request you can asses the response body of the first request: we can use a regex filter on the raw response of another request.

create a custom `dynamic value`:
[image: Adding a custom dynamic value]

then use the code below to set the custom dynamic value.

```js
function evaluate(context){
 // Set up your regex to extract the token
 var re = /<h2>([^<]+)<\/h2>/;
 
 // Replace the 'Login page' with your request name 
 var request = context.getRequestByName('Login page')
 var lastExchange = request.getLastExchange()
 var body =  lastExchange.responseBody
 
 var m = re.exec(body)
 return m[1]
};
```